# No results in a Salesforce standard list view when searching and sorting by date

Tags: list-view, sort

We have a standard Salesforce list view for Cases. It has 7 exact match filters on it as well as filter logic.

When we search the case list for a customer name, we get results.

When we sort the list by CreatedDate ascending, we get results.

When we sort the list by CreatedDate **descending, there are no results.**

This makes me suspect Salesforce is running in to some early truncation / limit of the list, and then applying cosmetic filtering afterwards, and dropping records. However I'm unable to find documentation about this behavior. What could cause this?

Comment: check to make sure after the last change that you have gone back to the first page of the listview

Comment: No pagination is in effect